# What is the strongest observed static stability in the troposphere?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere

I know that typical values for the Brunt–Väisälä frequency, $N$, are of the order $10^{-2} \mathrm{s}^{-1}$, but what is the strongest observed stability?  And how deep are such strong layers?

I am interested in running idealised simulations for such situations.